# I am getting this error when I start up my app in xcode

Tags: xcode

ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY:

This is a chat app I am working on and it pauses and goes to Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Please let me know if you have a solution the source code can be found at the bottom of this website...just apple f chatproject.zip

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html#l2

Also i get a warning on the line: [chatParser setDelegate:self]; sending'ioschatclientviewcontroller to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: Why don't you contact IBM?  I assume they will support the code they publish.

Comment: The Thread 1 alert happens for any crash when you don't have the debugger set up. It is telling you that the app crashed in the first line which is the best it can do when you have not set up the debugger. We can't tell from a tutorial what the problem with your code is. Might be a typo.